# Regenerate linkedin API secret key

Tags: linkedin-api, api-key

I want to regenerate the API consumer secret/secret key for my linkedin application, but the regenerate key button on the linkedin application only regenerates the OAuth 1.0a user secret.

I want a new OAuth2 secret key. I hope that I am not the only one who ever wanted to change their secret key.

After hours of googling, I can only find guides on how to locate the key, or dead links to linkedins old support forum.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is not presently possible to regenerate your OAuth 2.0 secret with LinkedIn.  Your best bet is to create a new application instance, and switch over to the new set of credentials.

This functionality has been requested very infrequently in the past, but it is something we're working on getting into the roadmap, regardless.